# Will this create new collection every time?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have written this code and I am a newbie for mongodb, Will this create new collection every time when page is called. If yes, then how can I prevent this ?

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//connect
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');

echo '<pre>';

//check connect
if($db){
    echo 'yeah connection done check </br>';
}else{
    echo 'nop';
    die;
}


//create table or collection
    $log = $db->createCollection("test_16042014",array());

    if($log){

//insert into
        $log->insert(array("name" => "sagar",
                            "email" => "test@gmail.com",
                            "date_time" => new MongoDate()
                            )
                    );
    }else{
        echo 'nop';
        die;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the MongoDB documentation for the [createCollection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) method: this command creates collection explicitly

> This method is used primarily for creating new capped collections.
>   This is also used to pre-allocate space for an ordinary collection.

If you call this method twice or if you try to create a collection that already exists you will get an error ("collection already exists").

> Collections in MongoDB are created implicitly when collection is
>   referenced in the command.

That means if you try to insert a document into a collection that does not yet exists, MongoDB will create a collection for you.

In your example, you can safely remove the command and just use insert method to create a new collection.

Comment: but it is not giving me an error, that my collection is already exist, then how can I know what's happenning

Comment: You will get that error if you try to enter this command in MongoDB shell. PHP will return you a MongoCollection object not an error.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if the collection exists I found this bit of code after a brief google. You need to use it to put an if clause around your create + insert so that it'll only insert if that collection doesn't already exist.

```
public function collection_exists($collection){

    if ($this->db->system->namespaces->findOne(array('name'=>'eI_db.'.$collection)) === null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

where $this->db is the currently referenced database.  You may have to tweak it to test with your setup.

There's also some mongo wrapper libraries which may be of use to you http://code.google.com/p/mongodb-morph/